# Mongoose: how to push to capped (limited size, rolling window) array in the document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document in the `testlog` collection that contains the `events` array, eg:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  user: 'joe',
  events: [ {}, {}, {}, ...]   // a possibly large array
}
```

Now, I'm updating these documents with new event items and just pushing to the array.
In time, these arrays can get quite large and overflow the 16MB limit on the doc size and my current idea is to limit the number of items in the array to, let's say, 5000. I would like to have a "rolling window" array, and it seems it can be done elegantly in the mongo shell: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#up._S_slice

However, I can't find the syntax for Mongoose to get it working.
If I try to set the Mongoose's update object like this (to push and slice at the same time):

```
var update = {        
        $push: {
          events: entry,
        },
        events: {
          $slice: -5000,
        },
      };
```

Mongoose complains it would be a conflict.

So, my next idea is to make Mongoose return new array size as the result of the push operation, and then to issue a separate slice command if the size is bigger than 5000.

Here, I also can't get the syntax right, how am I supposed to declare that I want Mongoose to return the _id and the new array size.
Something like this:

```
ar options = {
        upsert: true,
        select: {
          _id: 1,
          // arrSize: { $size: 'events' }, // this line does not work
          arrSize: { $size: '$events' }, // FIXED: but with $ it works!
        },
      };
```

Note that I could just omit the `select` from the `options` and have Mongoose return the entire updated object back but I want to avoid that - I don't want it returning multi-MB records over the wire when I don't need them (now), as I'm just logging.

---

EDIT:
I have figured out a typo in the syntax - I was missing a `$` to get the array length back. It is fixed now (and commented) above, but the main question of "how to do it efficently, to push and slice at the same time" still stands.
Never the less, I'll mark the only answer so far bellow as correct, pretty much stating it can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't do what you want exactly.

What I would personally do:

1. Stop using `mongoose` (trust me)
2. Execute an aggregate pipeline update instead (`mongoose` layers can't really deal with this for better or for worse)

Now I suspect you will prefer not to use these 2 methods therefor what I suggest is to maintain another field, `"eventsSize"`,

So your original update can just be the same with an `$inc` operator on that field. And your projection can just receive this `eventSize` field instead.

Comment: See the edit above, I've actually gotten the array length back (hate this syntax, BTW) so I do not need the redundant eventsSize field.
However, I still don't know how to do it in a single round-trip, so I ended up issuing the subsequent findById if the arrLength>5000, slicing the array at the client, and then another set command.
Not happy about it, but it should happen rarely, so I guess I can live with it.